# Detect open database connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, database-connection

somewhere in my application I have a memory leak, and I suspect it's because a database connection isn't being correctly closed or disposed of...

in asp.net, is there a way to detect how many database connections there currently are open?

Connection.Close never gets called in my app is the problem - NHibernate handles all of that, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: if there's something available in log4net - that is currently part of my app so would be able to use it

Comment: Have you used a memory profiler to look for the issue?

Comment: What makes you believe you have a memory leak? Where are you getting the stats that lead you to that conclusion? Database connections being left open would likely cause you more troubles before you ever noticed a real *memory leak* from it.

Comment: Memory profile doesn't really show me much, but I'm getting suddenly quite high memory usage (ok, relatively high, around 200MB) when just 30 users on the site maybe.  I'm getting the odd error saying the Session was null when it came to dispose of it...which is odd and is what leads me to believe the issue is in that area

Comment: 200MB doesn't seem out of line, necessarily. I'd be much more interested in the error. But that's a completely different question!

Comment: Are you disposing your NH Sessions after use? They should be short lived usually.

Comment: The leak isn't so much the question, it's more an is there a way to work that out...it's doing session per request by httpmodule, and the session *should* be disposed properly through that

Comment: If HTTP Session was null, then why do you think this has to do with Database connections?

Answer (score 0):

To detect open connections, you can use database management tool to connect to your test database and check active sessions there.

You can also use Performance Monitor to monitor open connections for .NET Framework applications.